# React: Trying to achieve a sequential fade-in effect with a Masonry layout but it's out of order

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I been trying to make a Masonry gallery with a sequential fade-in effect so that the pictures fade in one by one. And there is also a shuffle feature which will randomize the images and they fade in again after being shuffled.

here is the demo and the code:

https://tuo1t.csb.app/

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-swartz-tuo1t

When first visiting the page, the animation is correct. However once we click on the shuffle button, something weird happened: There are often some pictures don't fade-in sequentially after the image before them faded in, there is even no fade-in animation on them, they just show up out of order.

The way I achieved this animation is by adding a delay transition based on the index of the image, and use `ref` to track images.

first I initialize the `ref`

```
 let refs = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    refs[i] = useRef(null);
  }
```

and I render the gallery

```
 <Mansory gap={"1em"} minWidth={minWidth}>
        {imgs.map((img, i) => {
          return (
            <PicContainer
              index={img.index}
              selected={isSelected}
              key={img.index}
            >
              <Enlarger
                src={img.url}
                index={img.index}
                setIsSelected={setIsSelected}
                onLoad={() => {
                  refs[i].current.toggleOpacity(1); <--- start with zero opacity images till those are loaded
                }}
                ref={refs[i]}
                realIndex={i}
              />
            </PicContainer>
          );
        })}
      </Mansory>
```

for the every image component

```
class ZoomImg extends React.Component {
  state = { zoomed: false, opacity: 0 };

  toggleOpacity = o => {
    console.log("here");
    this.setState({ opacity: o }); <-- a setter function to change the opacity state via refs:
  };

  render() {
    const {
      realIndex,
      index,
      src,
      enlargedSrc,
      setIsSelected,
      onLoad
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <div style={{ margin: "0.25rem" }} onLoad={onLoad}>
        <Image
          style={{
            opacity: this.state.opacity,
            transition: "opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.25,0.46,0.45,0.94)",
            transitionDelay: `${realIndex * 0.1}s` <--- add a delay transition based on the index of the image.
          }}
          zoomed={this.state.zoomed}
          src={src}
          enlargedSrc={enlargedSrc}
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ zoomed: true });
            setIsSelected(index);
          }}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            this.setState({ zoomed: false });
            setIsSelected(null);
          }}
          renderLoading={
            <div
              style={{
                position: "absolute",
                top: "50%",
                color: "white",
                left: "50%",
                transform: "translateY(-50%} translateX(-50%)"
              }}
            >
              Loading!
            </div>
          }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I used `console.log("here");` in the setter function, which will be called for changing the opacity state via refs. There are 16 images, so initially it is called 16 times. But when I clicked on the shuffle button, you can see that it is called **fewer than** 16 times because some of the pictures show up directly without fading in.

I been struggling with this problem for days and really hope someone can give me some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your are adding only some new images in the shuffle method, one approach is to apply 0 opacity to all refs first, then wait a few ms to add 1 opacity again, like [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-monad-e1zo8).

But, I would recommend a better approach for animation, I love [shifty](https://github.com/jeremyckahn/shifty) and its Tweenable module.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! The fix works on Chrome but it doesn't work on Safari. Could you please take a look at this using Safari?